# Manipulating elements from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to add an li element to Local Storage and then recovering it to append it to an ul list.

Let's say that the li element is:

```
    <li>
      <label>Colors</label>
      <select>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
      </select>
      <label>Comments</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </li>
```

...and it came from a series a codes like:

```
   const li = document.createElement('li');
   const label = document.createElement('label');
   li.appendChild(label);
```

...and so on until the full li element from above was created.

I add the li element to local storage with:

```
    localStorage.setItem('listsOfColors', JSON.stringify(li));
```

And I recover it with:

```
    let colors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listsOfColors'));
```

But when I try to append it to a ul list:

```
    ul.appendChild(colors);
```

...it says that parameter 1 is not a node.

I already tried MANY approach to this matter but unsuccessful at the end. I went over a lot of options online but didn't find any that could help.

A hand here would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the result from localStorage as a jquery selector without JSON.parse.  It might turn your elements back into real elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you would need to write

```
ul.innerHTML = 'your stringified <li>';
ul.innerHTML += ''; // In case you want to append
```

appendChild takes an HTMLElement as a parameter. Since you just created a JSON element, that won't work. You should just store it as a string, then append it a a string.

(I won't go on about security issues, I think you know them already)

Comment: I'm almost there but there is still a thing I don't understand. I have the ul.innerHTML = stringified <li> like you said. How do I append it to <ul>? I mean, how do I convert it into a node so I can ul.appendChild(li)? Sorry if I didn't fully understand your explanation. I'm a beginner in JavaScript @trichetrice

Comment: You won't append it : `innerHTML` is the property that represents the HTMl inside of your `ul` : if you stringified your `li`, it should still look like HTML, and `innerHTML` will take is a HTML. If you want to see the difference, you can try using `ul.innerText`, which represents the text inside of your `ul` **not taken as HTML**

Comment: I understand know what you say but my goal is to take the <li> element with all his children inside local storage and recovering back again exactly how it is so I can append it to <ul>? That's my issue @trichetriche

Comment: And my answer will particulary suit you :)

Comment: I got it now but this solution works when there is only one <li> element. But what if there are more <li> being dynamically created in the DOM? I can't use the innerHTML property on the <ul> to all of them. That's why I was thinking on appending the <li> to <ul>...so I can loop through all the <li> elements and append each one at a time @trichetriche

Comment: Look at the second line of the code I gave you in my answer ;)

Comment: thanks for the patience man! i finally got it ;) @trichetriche

Comment: No problem ! Remember to mark your question as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

A `Node` object cannot be represented in JSON; JSON can only hold strings, numbers, plain objects, arrays and null. You can store a Node's `innerHTML` that will allow you to recreate it to a degree (you'd lose all event listeners and custom properties on it, of course).

A better approach would be to store just the data needed to recreate the UI. In this case, I'd just store the array of colour names, as that allows you to create the `<li>` element at any time.

Comment: then how do I grab the <li> element with all his children and put it inside local storage and then recover it back again so I can append it to the <ul> @Amadan?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this :

```
  localStorage.setItem('listsOfColors', JSON.stringify(li));
```

You have to get the element with his id for example :

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
```

and after you can store your element

```
  localStorage.setItem('listsOfColors', element);
```

Comment: Why would JSON.stringify an `document.getElementById(id);` work ?

Answer (score 0):

Data in LocalStorage is stored as key value pairs which are of type string.

JSON.parse returns a JSON object, function appendChild takes a DOM node as argument.

JSON != NODE

You could look into some library, for example:

[domJSON](https://azaslavsky.github.io/domJSON/)

Comment: then how do I grab the <li> element with all his children and put it inside local storage and then recover it back again so I can append it to the <ul>?